sendto sends packet twice
I am using unix sockets on layer 2 to send layer 2 packets in the air. I have an Alfa Awus adapter which I set to monitor mode via iwconfig wlanAdapter mode monitor command.
I have this c function which I call from the main. It runs fine, but funnily, it sends packet twice with sendto() function.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h> 
//more headers here

void wpaHandshakeStart(){
    
    //initialize data
    struct sockaddr_ll ll; // => link layer
    struct ifreq ifreq_i;
    
    int sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)); // => socket is layer 2


    //Network Interface Name
    memset(&ifreq_i,0,sizeof(ifreq_i)); memset(&ll,0,sizeof(ll));
    strncpy(ifreq_i.ifr_name,"wlx00181a0e1066",IFNAMSIZ-1); 
     
    if((ioctl(sock_raw,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifreq_i))<0)
        printf("indeks ioctl okumasında hata"); //İndeks Adını alma
     
    printf("indeks=%d\n",ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex);

    ll.sll_ifindex = ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex; ll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL); ll.sll_family = PF_PACKET;
    
    //binding socket to the interface
    if(bind(sock_raw, (struct sockaddr *)&ll, sizeof(ll)) == -1){ printf("Err: bind failed %d\n", errno); }
    
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65526); //memset(&buffer, '\0', 65511);
    
    
    //initialized, send auth message and WAIT... 11 seconds prefered
    
    //sending AUTH request 
    
    int sendlen = sendto(sock_raw, &authFromIphone, sizeof(authFromIphone), 0, 0, 0);
    //int sendlen = sendto(sock_raw, &authFromIphone, sizeof(authFromIphone), 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    if(sendlen < 0) { printf("gönderme hatası....send_len=%d....errno=%d\n", sendlen, errno); return;
    }else{ printf("AUTH request gonderildi, kod: %d\n", sendlen); }
    
}

Also funny thing is, WHATEVER packet I send, It sends the second one with 17 bytes less. An example:
54  1.884994038 7a:29:b6:e6:48:79   HuaweiTechno_e5:61:19   802.11  84  Authentication, SN=253, FN=0, Flags=........C
55  1.885410147 7a:29:b6:e6:48:79   HuaweiTechno_e5:61:19   802.11  67  Authentication, SN=253, FN=0, Flags=........

where 84 and 67 are sizes, this is a log from wireshark. I tried changing operating systems from kali linux to ubuntu, same thing happens. Also tried to set the last parameters of sendto(0, 0, 0) to zeros like this as you can see in the comments to see if a difference happens..
Nothing changed. If nothing is wrong with my code, i'll start assuming this is a network adapter issue. Thanks for any help.
NOTE: my authFromIphone is a char [] array like this or an unsigned char [] array like this, declared in a header file.
More Findings:
The second packet that is resent is about the kernel/OS itself. The OS, whether kali linux or ubuntu, resends the packets deleting all headers, and deleting the FCS.
The resent packet contains TX flag where the first packet I sent only contained RX flag. TX flag has a field which indicates the packet sent is a failed packet.
So the finding is this, If I send manually 802.11 frames with sendto, the OS recognizes it and resend a failure packet. But I am yet to figure out it decides failure based on what exactly ?
I tried killing NetworkManager I will also try to kill wpa_supplicant to see if it changes anything

ok I changed my physical adapter, and the issue is STILL there.

Could it be a ethernet hub/switch that repeats the packet?
I also wonder could a hub/switch truncate a frame, if there is some issue in length field of a header.

If I create a malformed packet, it doesn't get resent. I just found out. I think it is about kali/ubuntu's processing of 802.11 frames. My mac timestamp in the frame is for sure wrong, could be about that. or some other field that is in there. Will try and see. @SKi

I thought it'd be about sequence number, or the mac address. Yet the mac address is correct. Even though the seq number is incorrect, the resent byte has the same sequence number! :P
